# Alt+SysRq on a laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, thinkpad, sysrq

I have a Lenovo T410, and I would like to use the SysRq key, but whenever I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+letter combination, I keep getting the print screen dialog in linux.

Is there a  way around this? I have tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+letter as well as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+letter but to no avail for any of these. Any information to get around this would be great.

Answer (score 18):

It's not the same for all laptops unfortunately, but the general idea is to consult the manual to figure out the `SysRq` and then use `Alt` in addition to that, for example this is Lenovo X1:

`Lenovo X1 Carbon` user manual mentions `SysRq` is `Fn + S`, I managed to trigger `SysRq` combination using the following sequence:

- Press and **hold** `Fn + Alt + S`
- Release both `Fn` and `S`
- Press and release the desired key (e.g. `h` to show the `SysRq` help)
- Release `Alt`

Comment: it is just that Fn+S gives you printscreen (Checked on my thinkpad, I guessed they use same, X1 have several gens anyway so it is no one model). Alt+PtScr works too (alt first) as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key.

Comment: Confirmed, `Fn` + `S` does work when combined with `Alt` as described, but it's far easier to use `Alt` + `PrtSc`.  The process is the same - hold `Alt`, press and release `PrtSc`, then press and release `h`, then let go of `Alt`.  To confirm you can run `dmesg -w` in a terminal and then press `SysRq` +  `h` and you should see help messages come out if it's working.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling a bit with the answers given here, so maybe the following additional details might help others like me who have no prior experience with the sysrq key and would like to give it a try:

According to the manual, on my W510 the sysrq key is `Fn + PrintScreen`. (Googling `Thinkpad <your Thinkpad model> manual` should get you the manual. Then, search for `sysrq` in the manual itself.)

Finally, the magic sysrq key combinations can be reached through:

1. Hold down `Alt`.
2. Hold down `Fn` and `PrintScreen` for a moment and then release the two keys again. (They basically act as *one* key.) Meanwhile, keep holding down `Alt`.
3. Hit the remaining key of the magic sysrq key combination you would like to use (e.g. `h` for help or `b` for reboot).
4. Release `Alt`.

Side note 1: For ergonomic reasons I had swapped the `Fn` and `Ctrl` keys in my Thinkpad's BIOS (as is possible with practically any Thinkpad), so in my case I actually have to hit the left `Ctrl` key whenever I want to use the `Fn` key. In case of the sysrq key this is no different!

Side note 2: Whenever the [table on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) says a key combination will "display" certain information, what is meant is that the information is going to be written to the system log, which can be accessed through e.g. `$ dmesg` or `$ less /var/log/syslog`. At the same time, *if* you're logged in on any TTY (`Ctrl + Alt + F[1-6]`), then the same information will also be displayed there. Similarly, the kernel will respond with a message in the logs if a certain sysrq operation you're trying to use is disabled.

Side note 3: On Ubuntu there's a file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` controlling which magic sysrq key chords are available/enabled and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

On most laptops (I haven't verified on the T410):

- Press and hold both <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- Press and hold <kbd>SysRq</kbd>.
- Release <kbd>Fn</kbd>, and optionally <kbd>Alt</kbd> (but keep <kbd>SysRq</kbd> down).
- Press the letter or other key.
- Release everything and massage your sore fingers.

This holds for desktops as well: you can release <kbd>Alt</kbd> after you're holding <kbd>SysRq</kbd>, that way you only need to hold two keys at a time.

Comment: In my HP i do: Alt Fn SysRq (release Fn) (release SysRq) (release Alt)